# Make div go on screen bottom and not on parent bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a special html structure that emulate an app structure with page.

Please visit the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98d6btmL/16/) first to understand the problem.

```css
.screen-emulator {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}

.head {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.page {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
}

.page-test {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<div class="screen-emulator">
  <div class="head">Head</div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="page-test">page-test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So my question is: Is there a way in `css` to make `.page-test` go until the screen end and not until his parent (`.page`) end ?

The problem here is the `height: 100%;` property from `.page-test` that will make it go until `.page` bottom. I prefer to specify that **I will not be able to change the HTML structure** (even if it solves the problem) and that **I don't know in advance the height of `.head`**.

Comment: Have you tried using the **top** option in css?     Not the margin-top or padding-top just top

Comment: @EliKnaffo Mmmmh do you have an example ? I'm not sure that the `top` property will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think flexbox is the answer, if I understand the question correctly.

Start by explicitly setting all your elements' margin and padding to zero (sometimes called bootstrapping) this overrides any default user agent styles applied by the browser.

Set the `.screen-emulator` height to `100vh` and make it the flexbox container. You don't want to change the unknown height of the `.head` so we set `flex: none;`. The `.body` is the only flex item taking the remaining available height with `flex: 1;`.
https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/

```css
body,
.screen-emulator,
.head,
.body,
.page,
.page-test {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.screen-emulator {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.head {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  flex: none;
}

.body {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.page {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.page-test {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<div class="screen-emulator">

  <div class="head">
    <h1>Head</h1>
    <p>Random content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="page">

      <div class="page-test">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit amet. Posuere ac ut consequat
          semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet. Sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu. Phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus. Congue eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque diam. Consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus

        </p>
        <p>
          Nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis. Pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget. Tellus mauris
          a diam maecenas sed enim. Turpis massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit. Dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut. Id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales. Interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl

        </p>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.page-test {position: absolute;bottom: 0;width: 100%; height: 50%;background-color:violet;}
```

Is this what you are looking for?
I changed your height so it would better display in JsFiddle

Comment: Nope sorry `.page-test` have to go from `.page` top to screen bottom

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

You can calculate based on the view height `vh`. Note that `calc` is **not** supported in old browsers.

**Updated to new specifications**

Since the requirement is to cater for dynamic height of the `.head` element, you will need `JavaScript` to accomplish this. `CSS` is not designed to get values from the `DOM` and then apply it. That's why we have `JavaScript`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  resizePage();
}, false);

document.addEventListener("resize", resizePage);

function resizePage() {
  var head = document.querySelector(".head");
  var pageTest = document.querySelector(".page-test");

  pageTest.style.height = "calc(100vh - " + head.offsetHeight + "px)";
}
```

```css
.screen-emulator {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}

.head {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.page {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
}

.page-test {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<div class="screen-emulator">
  <div class="head">Head</div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="page-test">page-test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So this is the expected result but the problem is that I don't know in advance the height of `.head`. I update my question

Comment: @johannchopin I've updated my answer. Since it's dynamic, you'll need `JavaScript`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `min-height` or `height` of `.page-test` to `100vh`. This will ignore whatever height of the parent div and take that of the screen (if you don't mind overflows)

Update `css`

```
.page-test {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  /* min-height: 100vh; */
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: violet;
}
```

Comment: `100vh` is to much for `.page-test` because the `height` of `.head` is also taken into account so `.page-test` will exceed

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question, you want to change the order of your div's.
I did that with Bootstrap a few days ago for some mobile View with:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .col-xs-12 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div>This one is in Desktop view at the top, and in mobile at the end</div>
    <div>This one is at Desktop View at the End, and in mobile at the top</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can adjust this code then for your purposes.
Is that your question?